# Apple wants to make changes

Tags: macos, safari, password

I get a persistent pop-up window that states:
**Apple wants to make changes.** (See pic below)

Before I mindlessly press OK, I'd like to know what the action is about.

**Can anyone suggest how I might find out more about what is involved?**

- No application appears to be involved by name.
- The icon shows a "console" window inset over the locked padlock.
- I was running Safari 11.1.2 build 12605.3.8.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- It remained onscreen after I quit Safari.
- It requires three cancels to cancel.
- has recurred maybe half-a-dozen times in the last week.

**Note:** I have removed the user name which appears correctly for my account.

[image: Apple changes pop-up window]

UPDATE (Edit)

As per a suggestion in the comments, I ran Activity Monitor. It runs okay; but, I don't know what to look for so I tried all the variations I could think of without any Eureka moment.

Not very much later, I got this pop-up window asking for password permission to make changes. My User Name was right (erased from the screen-grab). Although the window identified the Activity Monitor as the application, there was no ? in the lower left corner for any more detail.

[image: Activity Monitor changes pop-up window]

I decided to click OK without password and it hated that. After a few tries, the window tried giving me my original password hint from the OS set-up. It took three "Cancel" clicks to go away. It hasn't recurred.

Meanwhile, the first anonymous "Apple wants… " pop-up window appears, from time to time, during Safari use. Occasionally, Safari becomes unstable and the main window closes.

UPDATE (Edit) Problem Resolved.

Today was a slow news day so I called Apple support who encouraged me to download and install **Malwarebytes** (Tip of the hat to them) which identified the location of suspicious files as similar to ones I found according to Apple Support discussion thread found in the answer given by Ashley.

The plist was a simple run-on-load and the other file was an executable and my unix is a bit…
 non-existent.

The Files found were:
~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchProvided
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchProvided.plist

Comment: Apple pop up will have the name of the app asking, and mostly only ask for Password not the user name (if you are the only user)

Comment: I would be tempted to use Activity Monitor to see if you can nail down what process is doing this. It sounds a little off to me...

Comment: fs_usage might be helpful as well.

Comment: You can also try running Malwarebytes (just the free mode is required) or other malware identification software and see if anything comes up.

Comment: I hope my curiosity is not dooming me to unrelieved future problems. Having never had any virus or previous malware experience, I might be pulling the tail of the tiger unwittingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mention of "Apple wants to make changes" in [this Apple discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8525964).  Someone there ran Malwarebytes, which found "Adware.OperatorMac", and mentions the following files:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSystem
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchSystem.plist
```

So, if you have those files, that would seem a good place to find out more.

I don't have 10.12.6 installed at the moment, but I do have machines running 10.11.6 and 10.13.6.  I don't have those files on either machine, so they aren't part of a standard install.

If you do have these files, perhaps you could post their contents as an update?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do not have these files in my user/Library folder.

Comment: I do have "SearchProvided" in those paths, which is quite similar, however, and more than a bit suspicious due to the similarity.

Comment: OK. I don't have those files on my 10.13.6 machine (I don't have time to check the other right now). They do sound suspicious (I think "SearchSystem" isn't an Apple term - they tend to use "Spotlight" in marketing, "MD" for metadata as a more technical term). Can you have a look at their contents (eg try dragging them onto TextEdit.app) and edit your question to explain your results? Then we can advise about what action to take.

Comment: Oh - another idea - do the dates on the files give you a clue as to how they might have been introduced? (Eg do you remember downloading / installing something at that time?) The dates can be inaccurate, particularly if this software is trying to cover it's tracks, but it's worth a look...