# Safari quits and then "Apple wants to make changes"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, mojave

Every so often, at least once a day it seems, Safari closes itself and then I get a pop-up prompt "Apple wants to make changes", asking me for my username and password to ... I guess authorise these changes.

I haven't been entering my username and password, I'm honestly wondering if it's a virus or so.

If I close the prompt it reappears, for a total of three appearances.

Then it won't reappear, at least immediately.

I can restart Safari at that point. Then the prompt reappears again, three more times.

What's going on and how do I stop it?

Currently I have Safari 13, but this happened since at least Safari 12 (it updated recently but was happening before then). I don't recall this happening before I got Mojave (but it might not be a Mojave-only issue).

---

Found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338341/150109) on the site for a different (v similar?) question, but those malicious files don't exist for me:

```
$ ls '~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSystem'
ls: ~/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSystem: No such file or directory
$ ls '~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchSystem.plist'
ls: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchSystem.plist: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370618/which-app-asking-for-elevated-permissions

Comment: Can you run a malware scan and see if something exists?