# Which app is asking for elevated permissions by “Apple wants to make changes”?

Tags: macos, security, permission

I have an associate who is getting elevated permissions pop-ups on their Mac with the message “Apple wants to make changes”. I suspect this may not be a legitimate request. How do I determine which process is asking for these permissions?

Comment: [safari-quits-and-then-apple-wants-to-make-changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370608/safari-quits-and-then-apple-wants-to-make-changes)

Comment: Yeah, the situation sounds similar, though I'm not sure if my colleague is having Safari issues. The question I'm asking is more specific though. How do I figure out which process is asking for elevated permissions?

Comment: I added [tag:Catalina] as this is a recent thing. If your colleague hasn't updated to Catalina, the answer is probably malware. (notify me by @ankii)

Comment: I have no idea if it's a recent thing or if they are using catalina, so i removed the tag. My question is how to determine which process is asking for those permissions.

Comment: Actually a good question. On Windows open windows are called out specifically in task manager and you can right-click on a process andd "go to [PROCESS]" if you are not sure. It is very handy. I've not seen similar functionality on macOS, unfortunately.

Comment: @ankii definitely not a catalina-only issue

Comment: I am surprised macOS doesn't let us see what, exactly, is asking for our Apple id password... somewhat scary